# Converting an integer number into its word representation

Tags: java, converting, numbers-to-words

I've written this code to convert an integer number into its word representation. I've tested it for many cases and it seems to be working as expected.

For example:

- 1000 displayed as "One Thousand"
- 99999 displayed as "Ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine"
- 999999999 displayed as "Nine hundred ninety nine million nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine"

However, I think it could be improved especially because I'm doing some checks repeatedly. Can someone suggest some refactoring for this?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NumberToWord {


    static HashMap<Integer,String> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
            static{
                numberMap.put(0,"Zero");
                numberMap.put(1,"One");
                numberMap.put(2,"Two");
                numberMap.put(3,"Three");
                numberMap.put(4,"Four");
                numberMap.put(5,"Five");
                numberMap.put(6,"Six");
                numberMap.put(7,"Seven");
                numberMap.put(8,"Eight");
                numberMap.put(9,"Nine");
                numberMap.put(10,"Ten");
                numberMap.put(11,"Eleven");
                numberMap.put(12,"Twelve");
                numberMap.put(13,"Thirteen");
                numberMap.put(14,"Fourteen");
                numberMap.put(15,"Fifteen");
                numberMap.put(16,"Sixteen");
                numberMap.put(17,"Seventeen");
                numberMap.put(18,"Eighteen");
                numberMap.put(19,"Nineteen");
                numberMap.put(20,"Twenty");
                numberMap.put(30,"Thirty");
                numberMap.put(40,"Forty");
                numberMap.put(50,"Fifty");
                numberMap.put(60,"Sixty");
                numberMap.put(70,"Seventy");
                numberMap.put(80,"Eighty");
                numberMap.put(90,"Ninety");
                numberMap.put(100,"Hundred");
                numberMap.put(1000,"Thousand");

            }

    public static String numberToWord(int number)
    {
        String wordForm = "";
        int quotient =0;
        int remainder = 0;
        int divisor = 0;
        if(number<1000000000 && number>=1000000)
        {
            divisor = 1000000;
            quotient = number/divisor;
            remainder = number % divisor;
            if(quotient!=0)
            wordForm += numberToWord(quotient) + " " + "Million";
            if(remainder!=0)
                wordForm+= " " + numberToWord(remainder);
        }
        else if(number<1000000 && number>=10000)
        {
            divisor = 1000;
            quotient = number/divisor;
            remainder = number % divisor;
            if(quotient!=0)
            wordForm += numberToWord(quotient) + " " + "Thousand";
            if(remainder!=0)
                wordForm+= " " + numberToWord(remainder);
        }
        else if(number<10000 && number>=1000)
        {
            divisor = 1000;
            quotient = number/divisor;
            remainder = number % divisor;
            if(quotient!=0)
            wordForm += numberMap.get(quotient) + "Thousand";
            if(remainder!=0)
                wordForm+= numberToWord(remainder);

        }else if(number<1000 && number>=100)
        {
            divisor = 100;
            quotient = number/divisor;
            remainder = number % divisor;
            if(quotient!=0)
            wordForm += numberMap.get(quotient) + " " + "Hundred";
            if(remainder!=0)
                wordForm +=numberToWord(remainder);

        }else if(number<100 && number>=10)
        {
            divisor = 10;
            quotient = number/divisor;
            remainder = number % divisor;
            if(quotient!=0)
                wordForm+= numberMap.get(quotient*divisor);
            if(remainder!=0)
                wordForm+= numberMap.get(remainder);


        }else if(number<10 && number>=0)
        {
            wordForm +=  numberMap.get(number);

        }
        return wordForm;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(numberToWord(100000));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(999999));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(678900));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(0));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(100567));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(4589));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(3333));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(67500));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(72));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(172346));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(890000));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(600700));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(67));
        System.out.println(numberToWord(999999999));
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is targeting c# and may be slighter different you might find this Code Review question useful - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14033/convert-number-to-words-web-application

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java

Answer (score 8):

Some notes:

1. `wordForm` should be `StringBuilder`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder Actually, I'd rename it to `result` too to make it clear that this object stores the result of the method.
2. Instead of the `System.out.println`s, use a parametrized unit test:

   ```
   import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Collection;

   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
   import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

   @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
   public class NumberToWordTest extends NumberToWord {

       private final String expected;
       private final int input;

       public NumberToWordTest(final String expected, final int input) {
           this.expected = expected;
           this.input = input;
       }

       @Parameters
       public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
           final Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
               { "One Hundred Thousand", 100000 },
               { "Nine HundredNinetyNine Thousand Nine HundredNinetyNine", 999999 },
               { "Six HundredSeventyEight Thousand Nine Hundred", 678900 },
               { "Zero", 0 },
               { "One Hundred Thousand Five HundredSixtySeven", 100567 },
               { "FourThousandFive HundredEightyNine", 4589 },
               { "ThreeThousandThree HundredThirtyThree", 3333 },
               { "SixtySeven Thousand Five Hundred", 67500 },
               { "SeventyTwo", 72 },
               { "One HundredSeventyTwo Thousand Three HundredFortySix", 172346 },
               { "Eight HundredNinety Thousand", 890000 },
               { "Six Hundred Thousand Seven Hundred", 600700 },
               { "SixtySeven", 67 },
               { "Nine HundredNinetyNine Million Nine HundredNinetyNine Thousand Nine HundredNinetyNine", 999999999 } };
           return Arrays.asList(data);
       }

       @Test
       public void test() {
           assertEquals(expected, NumberToWord.numberToWord(input));
       }

   }
   ```

   See: [Why not just use System.out.println()?](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#best_6) in the JUnit FAQ.
3. The `number` parameter could be `final`. It would help readers, because they know that the value does not change later. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods but you can find other questions on Programmers.SE in the topic.
4. According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-142311.html#430)

   > if statements always use braces {}.

   Omitting them is error-prone.
5. Numbers like `1000000000`, `1000000` etc. are magic numbers. You should use named constants.

   ```
   private static final int ZERO = 0;
   private static final int TEN = 10;
   private static final int ONE_HUNDRED = 100;
   private static final int ONE_THOUSAND = 1000;
   private static final int TEN_THOUSANDS = 10000;
   private static final int ONE_BILLION = 1000000000;
   private static final int ONE_MILLION = 1000000;
   ```
6. The method does not handle negative numbers. In this case you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of returning an empty string. (See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)
7. The reference type of `numberMap` should be simply `Map<Integer, String>`. See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
8. `numberMap` could be `private` and unmodifiable. It would prevent accidental modification.

   ```
   private static final Map<Integer, String> numberMap = createNumberMap();

   private static Map<Integer, String> createNumberMap() {
       final Map<Integer, String> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
       numberMap.put(0, "Zero");
       numberMap.put(1, "One");
       ...
       return Collections.unmodifiableMap(numberMap);
   }
   ```

   [What's the deal with Java's public fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959129/whats-the-deal-with-javas-public-fields)
9. I'd try to extract out a few methods:

   ```
   private static void calc(final StringBuilder result, final int number, 
           final int divisor, final String postfix) {
       final int quotient = number / divisor;
       final int remainder = number % divisor;
       if (quotient != 0) {
           result.append(numberToWord(quotient));
           result.append(" ");
           result.append(postfix);
       }
       if (remainder != 0) {
           result.append(" ");
           result.append(numberToWord(remainder));
       }
   }

   private static void calc2(final StringBuilder result, final int number, 
           final int divisor, final String postfix) {
       final int quotient = number / divisor;
       final int remainder = number % divisor;
       if (quotient != 0) {
           result.append(numberMap.get(quotient));
           result.append(postfix);
       }
       if (remainder != 0) {
           result.append(numberToWord(remainder));
       }
   }

   private static void calc3(final StringBuilder result, final int number, 
           final int divisor) {
       final int quotient = number / divisor;
       final int remainder = number % divisor;
       if (quotient != 0) {
           result.append(numberMap.get(quotient * divisor));
       }
       if (remainder != 0) {
           result.append(numberMap.get(remainder));
       }
   }
   ```

   It would remove some code duplication. Maybe you can find a better names for them.

   Then, the `numberToWord` looks like this:

   ```
   public static String numberToWord(final int number) {
       if (number < 0) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number can't be negative: " + number);
       }
       final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       if (number < ONE_BILLION && number >= ONE_MILLION) {
           calc(result, number, ONE_MILLION, "Million");
       } else if (number < ONE_MILLION && number >= TEN_THOUSANDS) {
           calc(result, number, ONE_THOUSAND, "Thousand");
       } else if (number < TEN_THOUSANDS && number >= ONE_THOUSAND) {
           calc2(result, number, ONE_THOUSAND, "Thousand");
       } else if (number < ONE_THOUSAND && number >= ONE_HUNDRED) {
           calc2(result, number, ONE_HUNDRED, " Hundred");
       } else if (number < ONE_HUNDRED && number >= TEN) {
           calc3(result, number, TEN);
       } else if (number < TEN && number >= ZERO) {
           result.append(numberMap.get(number));

       }
       return result.toString();
   }
   ```

Comment: palacsint do you think the code is easy to maintain and readable?

Comment: @Phoenix: I think it's fine, I didn't have any big problem during the review/refactoring. I'd not consider any of my comment serious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample I played with. Hope it's useful.

I'd consider decomposing this into reusable functions.

```
package com.bluenoteandroid.experimental.ints;

import static com.google.common.base.Optional.*;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import com.google.common.annotations.Beta;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public final class Ints {

    public static final int BASE_10 = 10;

    public static final String MINUS = "minus"; 

    public static final ImmutableMap<Integer, String> NUMBERS = ImmutableMap.<Integer, String>builder()
            .put(0,"zero")
            .put(1,"one")
            .put(2,"two")
            .put(3,"three")
            .put(4,"four")
            .put(5,"five")
            .put(6,"six")
            .put(7,"seven")
            .put(8,"eight")
            .put(9,"nine")
            .put(10,"ten")
            .put(11,"eleven")
            .put(12,"twelve")
            .put(13,"thirteen")
            .put(14,"fourteen")
            .put(15,"fifteen")
            .put(16,"sixteen")
            .put(17,"seventeen")
            .put(18,"eighteen")
            .put(19,"nineteen")
            .put(20,"twenty")
            .put(30,"thirty")
            .put(40,"forty")
            .put(50,"fifty")
            .put(60,"sixty")
            .put(70,"seventy")
            .put(80,"eighty")
            .put(90,"ninety")
            .put(100,"hundred")
            .put(1000,"thousand")
            .put(1000000,"million")
            .put(1000000000,"billion")
            .build();

    private Ints() { /* disabled */ }

    public static boolean allZeros(int[] range) {
        for (int n : range) {
            if (n != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Counts digits in an integer
     * @param number
     * @return digits count in the number
     */
    public static int digitCount(final int number) {
        return (int) ((number == 0) ? 1 : log10(abs(number)) + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Sums digits in an integer
     * @param number number
     * @return sum of the n's digits
     */
    public static int digitSum(final int number) {
        int _n = abs(number);
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            sum += _n % BASE_10;
        } while ((_n /= BASE_10) > 0);
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Gets digit index in an integer, counting from right 
     * @param number number
     * @param index (from right)
     * @return index-th digit from n
     */
    public static int digitFromRight(final int number, final int index) {
        checkElementIndex(index, digitCount(number));
        return (int) ((abs(number) / pow(BASE_10, index)) % BASE_10);
    }

    /**
     * Gets digit of index in an integer, counting from left 
     * @param number
     * @param index (from left)
     * @return index-th digit from n
     */
    public static int digitFromLeft(final int number, final int index) {
        checkElementIndex(index, digitCount(number));
        return digitFromRight(number, digitCount(number) - index - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a number to the array of it's digits
     * @param number number
     * @return array of digits
     */
    public static int[] digits(final int number) {
        return digits(number, digitCount(number));
    }

    /**
     * Converts a number to a reversed array of it's digits
     * @param number number
     * @return reversed array of digits
     */
    public static int[] digitsReversed(final int number) {
        return digitsReversed(number, digitCount(number));
    }

    private static int[] digits(final int number, final int digitCount) {
        final int[] digits = new int[digitCount];

        int _n = abs(number);
        int i = digitCount - 1;
        do {
            digits[i--] = _n % BASE_10;
        } while ((_n /= BASE_10) > 0);
        return digits;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a number to a reversed array of it's digits
     * @param number number
     * @param digitCount digit count
     * @return reversed array of digits
     */
    private static int[] digitsReversed(final int number, final int digitCount) {
        final int[] reversedDigits = new int[digitCount];

        int _n = abs(number);
        int i = 0;
        do {
            reversedDigits[i++] = _n % BASE_10;
        } while ((_n /= BASE_10) > 0);
        return reversedDigits;
    }

    public static int fromDigits(final int[] digits) {
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;
        do {        
            n += digits[i++];
            if (i >= digits.length) {
                break;
            }
            n *= BASE_10;
        } while (true);
        return n;
    }

    public static int fromDigitsReversed(final int[] reversedDigits) {
        int n = 0;
        int i = reversedDigits.length;
        do {        
            n += reversedDigits[--i];
            if (i <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            n *= BASE_10;
        } while (true);
        return n;
    }

    @Beta
    public static String numberInWords(final int number) {
        Optional<String> name = fromNullable(NUMBERS.get(number));
        if (name.isPresent()) {
            return name.get();
        } else {
            return numberToName(number);
        } 
    }

    private static String numberToName(int number) {        
        final LinkedList<String> words = Lists.newLinkedList();
        final int[] digits = digitsReversed(number);        
        for (int factor = 0; factor < digits.length; factor += 3) {
            final int[] range = Arrays.copyOfRange(digits, factor, factor + 3);
            if (allZeros(range)) {
                continue;
            }

            switch (factor) {
            case 0: /* nothing */
                break;
            case 3: /* thousand */
                words.addFirst(NUMBERS.get((int) pow(BASE_10, 3)));
                break;
            case 6: /* million */
                words.addFirst(NUMBERS.get((int) pow(BASE_10, 6)));
                break;
            case 9: /* billion */
                words.addFirst(NUMBERS.get((int) pow(BASE_10, 9)));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown factor: " + factor);
            }

            String part = tripletToWords(range);
            words.addFirst(part);
        }

        if (number < 0) { // negative
            words.addFirst(MINUS);
        }

        return Joiner.on(' ').join(words);
    }

    private static String tripletToWords(final int[] reversedDigits) {
        checkArgument(reversedDigits.length == 3, "This is not a triplet of digits, size: " + reversedDigits.length);

        final int number = fromDigitsReversed(reversedDigits);

        final int[] range = Arrays.copyOfRange(reversedDigits, 0, 2);
        final String dubletWords = dubletToWords(range);

        if (number >= 100) {
            final int thirdDigit = reversedDigits[2];
            final int factor = BASE_10 * BASE_10;
            final String dublet = allZeros(range) ? null : dubletWords;
            return Joiner.on(' ').skipNulls().join(
                    NUMBERS.get(thirdDigit),
                    NUMBERS.get(factor),
                    dublet);
        } else {
            return dubletWords;
        }
    }

    private static String dubletToWords(final int[] reversedDigits) {
        checkArgument(reversedDigits.length == 2, "This is not a dublet of digits, size: " + reversedDigits.length);

        final int number = fromDigitsReversed(reversedDigits);

        Optional<String> name = fromNullable(NUMBERS.get(number));
        if (name.isPresent()) {
            return name.get();
        } else {
            final int firstDigit = reversedDigits[0];
            final int secondDigit = reversedDigits[1];
            final int tens = BASE_10 * secondDigit;
            return Joiner.on('-').join(
                    NUMBERS.get(tens),
                    NUMBERS.get(firstDigit));
        }
    }
}
```

With unit tests:

```
package com.bluenoteandroid.experimental.ints;

import static com.bluenoteandroid.experimental.ints.Ints.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import com.bluenoteandroid.experimental.ints.IntsTests.*;

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    CountTest.class, 
    SumTest.class, 
    GetDigitRightTest.class, 
    GetDigitRightPeconditionsTest.class,
    GetDigitLeftTest.class, 
    GetDigitLeftPeconditionsTest.class,
    DigitArrayTest.class,
    FromDigitArrayTest.class,
    ReverseDigitArrayTest.class,
    FromReverseDigitArrayTest.class,
    NumberToWordTest.class
})
public class IntsTests {

    @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)   
    public static class CountTest {

        private final int input;
        private final int expected;

        public CountTest(final int input, final int expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Integer[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Integer[][] {
                { 0, 1 }, /* input, expected */
                { -1, 1 },
                { 900003245, 9 },
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldCountDigits() {
            assertThat(digitCount(input), is(expected));
        }
    }

    @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
    public static class SumTest {

        private final int input;
        private final int expected;

        public SumTest(final int input, final int expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Integer[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Integer[][] {
                { 0, 0 }, /* input, expected */
                { -1, 1 },
                { 1001, 2 },
                { 1234, 1+2+3+4 }
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldSumDigits() {
            assertThat(digitSum(input), is(expected));
        }
    }

    @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
    public static class GetDigitRightTest {

        private final int input;
        private final int index;
        private final int expected;

        public GetDigitRightTest(final int input, final int index, final int expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.index = index;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Integer[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Integer[][] {
                { 0, 0, 0 }, /* input, expected */
                { -1004, 0, 4 },
                { 1234, 1, 3 },
                { -1234, 2, 2 },
                { 1234, 3, 1 },
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldGetDigits() {
            assertThat(digitFromRight(input, index), is(expected));
        }
    }

    public static class GetDigitRightPeconditionsTest {

        @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
        public void shouldNotAllowNegativeIndex() {
            digitFromRight(1234, -1);
        }

        @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
        public void shouldNotAllowToBigIndex() {
            digitFromRight(1234, 4);
        }
    }

    @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
    public static class GetDigitLeftTest {

        private final int input;
        private final int index;
        private final int expected;

        public GetDigitLeftTest(final int input, final int index, final int expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.index = index;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Integer[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Integer[][] {
                { 0, 0, 0 }, /* input, expected */
                { -1004, 0, 1 },
                { 1234, 1, 2 },
                { -1234, 2, 3 },
                { 1234, 3, 4 },
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldGetDigits() {
            assertThat(digitFromLeft(input, index), is(expected));
        }
    }

    public static class GetDigitLeftPeconditionsTest {

        @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
        public void shouldNotAllowNegativeIndex() {
            digitFromLeft(1234, -1);
        }

        @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
        public void shouldNotAllowToBigIndex() {
            digitFromLeft(1234, 4);
        }
    }

    public static class DigitArrayTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldGetAllDigits() {
            final int[] result = digits(-1234);
            final int[] expected = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
            assertThat(result, is(expected));
        }
    }

    public static class FromDigitArrayTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldConvertDigits() {
            final int result = fromDigits(new int[] {1,2,3,4});
            final int expected = 1234;
            assertThat(result, is(expected));
        }
    }

    public static class ReverseDigitArrayTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldGetAllDigits() {
            final int[] result = digitsReversed(-1234);
            final int[] expected = new int[] {4,3,2,1};
            assertThat(result, is(expected));
        }
    }

    public static class FromReverseDigitArrayTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldConvertDigits() {
            final int result = fromDigitsReversed(new int[] {4,3,2,1});
            final int expected = 1234;
            assertThat(result, is(expected));
        }
    }

    @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
    public static class NumberToWordTest {

        private final int input;
        private final String expected;

        public NumberToWordTest(final int input, final String expected) {
            this.input = input;
            this.expected = expected;
        }

        @Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 0, "zero" },
                { 1, "one" },
                { 10, "ten" },
                { 15, "fifteen" },
                { 60, "sixty" },
                { 67, "sixty-seven" },
                { 72, "seventy-two" },
                { 101, "one hundred one" },
                { 205, "two hundred five" },
                { 4589, "four thousand five hundred eighty-nine" },
                { 3333, "three thousand three hundred thirty-three" },
                { 67500, "sixty-seven thousand five hundred" },
                { 100000, "one hundred thousand" },
                { 100567, "one hundred thousand five hundred sixty-seven" },
                { 172346, "one hundred seventy-two thousand three hundred forty-six" },
                { 600700, "six hundred thousand seven hundred" },
                { 678900, "six hundred seventy-eight thousand nine hundred" },
                { 890000, "eight hundred ninety thousand" },
                { 999999, "nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine" },
                { 999999999, "nine hundred ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine" },
                { 1999999999, "one billion nine hundred ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine" },
                { -21239, "minus twenty-one thousand two hundred thirty-nine"},
            });
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {
            assertEquals(expected, numberInWords(input));
        }

    }
}
```